# How to read, load and play videos from directory

Tags: android, video, directory, load

I'm trying to create an application that reads mp4 files from a directory and then play.

I have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Random r = new Random();
List<String> videoPathes = new ArrayList<String>();
int i=r.nextInt(3-0);
private VideoView videoview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_video);
    videoPathes.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myapp/intro1.mp4");
    videoPathes.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myapp/intro2.mp4");
    videoPathes.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myapp/intro3.mp4");



    videoview.setVideoPath(videoPathes.get(i));
    videoview.start();

    videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mp){
            i = (i + 1) % videoPathes.size();

            videoview.setVideoPath(videoPathes.get(i));
            videoview.start();
        }
    });

}
}
```

But the Pathes are included in the app.. I don't need that, because I would have to update the application each time I add a new video... so thi is not practical.

Any idea?... help please, is very important for me.

P.S. is important to keep the random "function" to star whiout order (always first).

Thanks.

Comment: See the following link http://sree.cc/google/android/playing-the-video-in-sd-card-of-android to see how to read videos on external storage.

Comment: Are you not able to play videos?  Or are you trying to figure out how to show add videos to this list without updating the app?  Not clear to me what your actual issue is here.

Comment: I need to load videos in the app without writhe the pathes in the app. Just update the videos in directory and the app read them.